# Get values from datatable error Object does not match target type

Tags: c#

I am trying to get all values  from all datatable rows in a specific column where  another column has a value of x;
I am struggling to get it working. I have tried many variants but always get the error: Object does not match target type.
This is de relevant code I use:

```
 var toCompaireList = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(collNames[i]);
                EnumerableRowCollection<string> dValue = from row in dataTableTemp.AsEnumerable()
                                                         where row.Field<int>(columnNames[i]) >= ((int)property.GetValue(type)) - minPrecision &&
                                                               row.Field<int>(columnNames[i]) <= ((int)property.GetValue(type)) + plusPrecision
                                                         select row.Field<string>(opdr);

                if (dValue != null && dValue.ToList().Count > 0)
                {
                    toCompaireList = dValue.ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
```

Here a resume of Stacktrace:

> at StatisticMethods.<>c__DisplayClass3_2.b__2(DataRow row) in C:\Users\Program\StatisticMethods.cs:line 215
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Program.StatisticMethods.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Program\StatisticMethods.cs:line 219

I have no idea what or where the type mismatch is.
Hope someone can help,

Groover

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What I understand is that you are trying to retrieve the value in a single column from all the rows present in a dataTable. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. but I only want the values of column[0](string) where column  x has a value between y and z (integer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve the value in a single column from all the rows present in a dataTable. Then, this query should be sufficient.

```
var retrieved =dataTableTemp.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                             .Where(row => (int.Parse(row[x].Tostring()) >=y && (int.Parse(row[x].Tostring()) <= z)
                             .Select(row[requiredColumnName]);
```

The values in the `retrieved` enumerable is of type object. so you can cast to the specific type.

```
var mainResult= retrieved.cast<TypeName>().ToList();
```

If you have any trouble using this, please leave a comment.